# How can i check a application is service application or not in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am writing program to know from the task manager which are Service application .

I able to display all the application in a List Box. From that I have to check which are service application and which are not.

```
enter code here

   For Each OneProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        ListBox1.Items.Add(OneProcess.ProcessName)
   Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get all services in the machine use System.ServiceProcess.
Add reference to System.ServiceProcess

```
  Dim srvcs() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
    srvcs = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices()
    For Each s As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController In srvcs
        ListBox1.Items.Add(s.DisplayName)
    Next
```

and to check if service is running

```
  If s.Status = ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
```

For more info check
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: i have several service application of my own . i have took out from the       list box. I can do  this by     string starts with........... is there any other method to list out...